# Google Cloud AppEngine timeout error for MongoDB with port 27017. Works perfectly from local machine

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've setup a Google VM(compute Engine) with Bitnami's MongoDB. Added firewall for the port as well. I'm able to connect to the same MongoDB instance from my local machine from console and through Mongoose. But I'm getting timeout error when I tried to connect from my Google Cloud AppEngine.
My Question is, are they blocking outbound request to MongoDB instance??(pinging to the IP address is working).

> Note: Firewall rules has been added. Static External IP is configured,
>   and I'm able to connect from my local machine too.

Error message

```
    Could not connect to MongoDB!
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT <host-ip-address>:27017
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1174:14)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connect ETIMEDOUT <host-ip-address>' }
```

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49035727/3615567). Similar problem. You have to configure App Engine networking rules as well

Comment: Not similar problem :( . Forget about my application. I cant even connect to mongolab's mongodb service from my app-engine console. same command working from my desktop .

Comment: What do you mean your app-engine console? Can you add what command works from the desktop and fails in the Cloud, and how are you issuing it in the Cloud? Also, can you please paste some code from App Engine that tries to connect to the Mongo deployment on your VM, but fails?

Comment: Google is providing ssh console. Please check https://console.cloud.google.com/ for more clarification. If you don't know how to connect to mongodb from terminal/console , please check this link: https://docs.mongodb.com/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb-shell/. Command will be something like                            mongo --host mongodb0.tutorials.com:28015. The above command is the one working from my local machine and not working from google app engine terminal; FYI, I tried using mongodb service provided by mongo lab also, but no luck.

Comment: For those who are struggling with same issue, I gave up and created a VM instead of app-engine and everything works fine.

Comment: I have this problem too!

Comment: @JamesTrickey Google have many restrictions. they dont allow smtp on default ports and many other things. Not sure what is happening in this case because I couldn't find any documentation regarding this issue. 
The funny part is, google will let you install MongoDB on AppEngine and it will reset all the changes when u restart the AppEngine.
BTW, I deleted my AppEngine and happily using Compute engine :)

Comment: Thanks Manu. Yeah I followed your advice and am doing the same. It seems a shame tho - i'm sure it is possible but there is so little documentation on it.